# Custom suggestions in SearchView in menu

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a `searchview` in my `menu` (toolbar). It performs a search query in my recycler view and it works fine. I need to add a custom search suggestions to my `searchview` and I can't find any way to add it to a default `searchview` menu item. I have shared the code of my menu items and search query.

**Menu XML file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/actionSearch"
        android:title=""
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/actionAdd"
        android:title=""
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_add"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/actionImport"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Import from phone"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/actionExport"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Export as VCF"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/actionSettings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```

**Search Query:**

```
private fun search(searchView: SearchView) {
        searchView.queryHint = "Search Here"
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false)
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean = false
            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
                initRecentRecyclerView()
                mAdapter2.getFilter().filter(newText)
                recentAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText)
                return true
            }})
        MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(search, object : MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener {
            override fun onMenuItemActionExpand(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
                initRecentRecyclerView()
                return true
            }

            override fun onMenuItemActionCollapse(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
                recentRecyclerView.visibility = View.GONE
                return true
            }
        })
        searchView.setOnFocusChangeListener({ _: View, b: Boolean ->
            if(!b){
                recentRecyclerView.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        })
        searchView.setOnCloseListener{
            recentRecyclerView.visibility = View.GONE
            true
        }
        searchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener({ view: View, b: Boolean ->
            if(!b){
                try {
                    recentRecyclerView.visibility = View.GONE
                }catch(e: Exception){}
            }
        })
    }
```

actionSearch is the id of my searchView, searchView is the reference I have used in my `kotlin` code. I need to show a list of suggestions in my `searchview`. Hope that someone can help me out!